# Printing on CD/DVD with Epson Stylus Photo R285 (or similar)

Tags: cd, printing

I need to print on CD/DVD with my Epson R285. Please indicate a method or Ubuntu software for printing on CD/DVD surfaces.

Comment: Update: printing from LibreOffice affect on colour reproduction, what is not occurs when I print from original EpsonCD software in Windows XP. Printing from XP works fine under VirtualBox WinXP machine. I guess it's a matter of colour management either by LibreOffice or Epson drivers (Epson R285).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution by creating a user-defined template in gLabels Label Designer (v. 2.2.8). I just defined dimensions of CD table of my Epson R285 jet printer, without changing any values regarding print margins. When you print on CD/DVD select in Print Source pull-down menu 'Print to CD' option.

V.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a good CD cover template for your printer.

Then you can use any program you want to make your cd label. Everything from [gimp](http://doctormo.org/install.pl?gimp), openoffice draw to [inkscape](http://doctormo.org/install.pl?inkscape) or [scribus](http://doctormo.org/install.pl?scribus). There is also a program specifically for labels called [glabels](http://doctormo.org/install.pl?glabels) which may already have a good template you can use.

I have an SVG template which I use with my Canon iP5000 which positions the CD image on a page size the printer is expecting. I developed the template with a lot of trial and error using a non-printable cd which I could wipe the ink off and try again and now I can happily make CDs in inkscape, export to PDF and print them out.

Comment: Thank you for comprehensive answer. However, I would like to be sure that printing on CD/DVD surfaces will be like as what you see is what you get. So, I was looking for software, like Epson PrintCd but for linux (Ubuntu), without success so far :)

Comment: There isn't software like that because it confuses two activities. One of design/art and one of templates. You will get what you see when you have a template for your printer, or if you find one in the glabels program.

Comment: I found an OpenOffice template for another Canon inkjet printer (the file name is OpenOffice_template_for_CDPrinting_note_set_cdprint_5_inches.odg). And it print out almost perfectly with Epson R285. I just made little layout adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

The use of CD jacket printing allow the customers to create their products look more good-looking and beautiful. Moreover, it brings out the best person artistic thoughts out in the open, so that everyone could advantage from it.

http://www.emanprinting.net/cd-jackets-printing.php

Answer (score 0):

I have an Epson R265. To print to a printable CD/DVD I used Inkscape.

I opened Inkscape and selected the provided CD template (File - New from template - CD label). Created my artwork using the template and clicked - File - Print.

In the print dialogue I selected the R265 as the printer to print to. The current drivers provide all the print to CD options you need.

In the print dialogue under the Page Setup tab set Paper Type to - Inkjet paper and Paper Source to - Print to CD. Under the Advanced tab set Shrink page to - Crop.

There are numerous other printer parameters you can fiddle with, but that is basically it. When you create the artwork you should put your graphics and text on layers above Layer 1 (which shows the disc outline) and then before printing hide Layer 1, otherwise it will print the circles of the outline as well as your artwork.

This is not quite as fool proof as using the Epson utility under Windows, but it is pretty simple.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It would help if you shortened and broke down that wall of text into more easily readable, itemised lists or paragraphs for each step.